# How can I unify/merge two of my accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I have two accounts:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73606/der

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53124/ze1

They appear in the screen in an alternating manner. I want to unify them in one account, namely the first one (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73606/der). Then:  How I can do this?

Comment: I see your accounts are still separate; have you tried merging them as stated below? If unsuccessful, use the [contact us](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request a merge.

Comment: @Behaviour: Ok I send a request to the center.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Standard method

Use the [Contact Us form](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) with the reason "merge user profiles".

#### DIY method

If you still have access to both accounts, you can try adding login method you use for one account to another account. To do this, click "my logins... add more logins" on the profile page. The system will detect that the same login method is used for both, and will merge them automatically.