# Why I am failing to complete "about me" section?

Tags: discussion, support, user-profile

I am trying to update my profile section to get the 'Autobiographer' badge. I uploaded photo (less than 2 mb) and completed the about me section too. But when I click 'save profile' option, the following line appears always, though I have the full access of my account.

"This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account."

Comment: Most likely you have more than one account - you probably need to get them [merged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/merge-accounts/info), At least this is the impression I got from: [Cannot update my profile - email in use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158260) and [Can't edit my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222935).

Comment: I can't remember if I have more than one account or not? Now how this issue can be resolved. Please help.

Comment: To merge: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18786/442